# Is a private constructor the default constructor, and what is its use?

Tags: java

If I write private constructor in java than it works like default constructor? And what is the use of private constructor in class?

```
public class BillPughSingleton {
private BillPughSingleton() {
}

private static class LazyHolder {
    private static final BillPughSingleton INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
}

public static BillPughSingleton getInstance() {
    return LazyHolder.INSTANCE;
}
```

}

Also explain how this code will work and what value it return

Comment: It provide only one instance of BillPughSingleton class. It's Singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 3):

private constructor without parameters *prevents* `BillPughSingleton` from being created outside the `BillPughSingleton` scope, e.g.

```
   // Compile time error: BillPughSingleton() is private 
   BillPughSingleton instance = new BillPughSingleton();

   // The right and the ONLY way to get (single) instance:
   BillPughSingleton instance = BillPughSingleton.getInstance();
```

if *no constructors* (including `private BillPughSingleton()`) are declared, the

```
   // if no constructors are declared, this wrong call becomes possible
   BillPughSingleton instance = new BillPughSingleton();
```

becomes possible via *default* constructor syntax.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry Bychenko :)